# My local Tomcat is not being accessable from other Win8 PC of the network

Tags: apache, tomcat6, lan

I have configured two instance of Tomcat 6.0 in my local machine with two different port number to access. All going well like I can access application both as `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8081` . even I can access from my local browser using my local IP as `192.168.5.20:8080` and `192.168.5.20:8081`

**Problem is:** From another computer of my network `192.168.5.20:8080` is accessible but `192.168.5.20:8081` is not.

How can I access the 8081 port from another computer?

Comment: You should probably mention which OS you're using. Also, what are you doing with Apache? You didn't mention it in your question, but you added it as a tag...

Comment: Tag was just for related topics. Thanks man I have got my problem solved. You can take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set rule for inbound request:

1/ Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.

2/ In the left pane, click Advanced settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

3/ In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, and then, in the right pane, click New Rule.

4/ select port and click next, now enter your port in specific local ports OR check on All local port.

5/ Set preferred settings